# Android using jaudiotagger

Tags: java, android, jaudiotagger

I try to use jaudiotagger like this
but it crashes

Main app.java :
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;

```
import org.jaudiotagger.audio.AudioFile;
import org.jaudiotagger.audio.AudioFileIO;
import org.jaudiotagger.audio.AudioHeader;
import org.jaudiotagger.audio.exceptions.CannotReadException;
import org.jaudiotagger.audio.exceptions.CannotWriteException;
import org.jaudiotagger.audio.exceptions.InvalidAudioFrameException;
import org.jaudiotagger.audio.exceptions.ReadOnlyFileException;
import org.jaudiotagger.tag.FieldDataInvalidException;
import org.jaudiotagger.tag.FieldKey;
import org.jaudiotagger.tag.KeyNotFoundException;
import org.jaudiotagger.tag.Tag;
import org.jaudiotagger.tag.TagException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class App extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */


    private TextView txt1;
    private TextView txt2;
    private TextView txt3;
    private TextView txt4;
    private TextView txt5;
    private TextView txt6;
    private TextView txt7;
    private TextView txt8;
    private TextView txt9;






    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

       // try
        //{
        File mp3 = new File("/sdcard/test.mp3");
        AudioFile f = null;
        try {
            f = AudioFileIO.read(mp3);
        } catch (CannotReadException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            txt1.setText(e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            txt1.setText(e.toString());
        } catch (TagException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            txt1.setText(e.toString());
        } catch (ReadOnlyFileException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            txt1.setText(e.toString());
        } catch (InvalidAudioFrameException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            txt1.setText(e.toString());
        }
        Tag tag = f.getTag();
        AudioHeader AudioHeader = f.getAudioHeader();
        txt1.setText(tag.getFirst(FieldKey.ARTIST));
        txt2.setText(tag.getFirst(FieldKey.ALBUM));
        txt3.setText(tag.getFirst(FieldKey.TITLE));
        txt4.setText(tag.getFirst(FieldKey.COMMENT));
        txt5.setText(tag.getFirst(FieldKey.YEAR));
        txt6.setText(tag.getFirst(FieldKey.TRACK));
        txt7.setText(tag.getFirst(FieldKey.DISC_NO));
        txt8.setText(tag.getFirst(FieldKey.COMPOSER));
        txt9.setText(tag.getFirst(FieldKey.ARTIST_SORT));




        try {
            tag.setField(FieldKey.ARTIST,"Kings of Leon");
        } catch (KeyNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            txt1.setText(e.toString());
        } catch (FieldDataInvalidException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            txt1.setText(e.toString());
        }
        try {
            AudioFileIO.write(f);
        } catch (CannotWriteException e) {
            txt1.setText(e.toString());
        }
       /* }
        catch(Exception x)
        {
            txt1.setText(x.toString());
        }
        */




    }
}
```

Logcat :

> 02-22 21:12:22.546: E/AndroidRuntime(19738): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   02-22 21:12:22.546: E/AndroidRuntime(19738):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.mp3.tag.editor.alexander.fuchs/com.mp3.tag.editor.alexander.fuchs.App}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 02-22 21:12:22.546:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19738):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
>   02-22 21:12:22.546: E/AndroidRuntime(19738):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
>   02-22 21:12:22.546: E/AndroidRuntime(19738):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117) 02-22
>   21:12:22.546: E/AndroidRuntime(19738):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
>   02-22 21:12:22.546: E/AndroidRuntime(19738):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 02-22
>   21:12:22.546: E/AndroidRuntime(19738):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 02-22 21:12:22.546:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19738):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691) 02-22
>   21:12:22.546: E/AndroidRuntime(19738):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 02-22
>   21:12:22.546: E/AndroidRuntime(19738):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 02-22 21:12:22.546:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19738):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
>   02-22 21:12:22.546: E/AndroidRuntime(19738):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665) 02-22
>   21:12:22.546: E/AndroidRuntime(19738):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 02-22 21:12:22.546:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(19738): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   02-22 21:12:22.546: E/AndroidRuntime(19738):  at
>   com.mp3.tag.editor.alexander.fuchs.App.onCreate(App.java:72) 02-22
>   21:12:22.546: E/AndroidRuntime(19738):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   02-22 21:12:22.546: E/AndroidRuntime(19738):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
>   02-22 21:12:22.546: E/AndroidRuntime(19738):  ... 11 more

Answer (score 2):

There two blockers
to using jaudiotagger on Android:

## 1 - javax.swing

## 2 - javax.imageio

these two Classes isn't supported by android and jaudiotagger uses them

To solve your problem:
Fix the sources so they don't depend no more on these two JAVAX Classes

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this line causes the crash, because `f` is null:

```
Tag tag = f.getTag();
```

You shouldn't ignore the exception in the way you do, as if you got an exception, you just print something and continue with a bad state (in this case - `f` is still null)

Comment: But I need to use f, without f the application wouldnt even show something

Comment: So find what's your problem first, because for some reason, f seems to be null, and all the trace that you gave have nothing to do with the reason for that. And also, there's no point in using f when it gives you an error.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to check that f != null before you get the tag.

```
Tag r_tag = null;
File testFile = new File(filename);
MP3File f = null;
try {
    f = (MP3File)AudioFileIO.read(testFile);
} catch (CannotReadException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (TagException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ReadOnlyFileException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvalidAudioFrameException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if(f != null) {
    f.getTagOrCreateAndSetDefault();
    r_tag = f.getID3v2TagAsv24();
}
return r_tag;
```